# Cassandra hangs at every start for 2-3 hours after "nodetool repair -dcpar"

Tags: cassandra

Cassandra cluster in 2 DC, 22 nodes in each DC. 
Data size on each node 20TB. 
Cassandra version 3.7

In cluster was executed "nodetool repair -dcpar".
While executing repair for some servers was written to log errors like this:

```
RepairRunnable.java:256 - Repair session a398c8c0-3977-11e7-944c-a54828f083d5 for range [(5551975584759480600,5552048774757593067]] failed with error Endpoint /10.128.85.17 died
```

When repair finished, at every start (not just first time) on ANY node in cluster the Cassandra service hangs up for 2-3 hours. 
The last messages in log (before it hangs) are:

```
INFO  [main] 2017-05-16 16:42:14,457 ColumnFamilyStore.java:405 - Initializing system_schema.aggregates
INFO  [main] 2017-05-16 16:42:14,467 ColumnFamilyStore.java:405 - Initializing system_schema.indexes
INFO  [main] 2017-05-16 16:42:14,468 ViewManager.java:139 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_schema as storage service is not initialized
```

While service hanging the CPU usage is 100%, but IO operations near 0%.

Before "repairing" service usualy started in 30 seconds.

How to fix it?

Comment: repair -dcpar will stream data across data centers, So for 20 TB of data, streaming takes long time and using high CPU usage and finally node dies. To optimize provide What is the Snitch and how many nodes in each data center you use and how many keyspace, replication factor of the keyspaces and number of column families in each keyspace.

Comment: This problem is partially solved by updrading Cassandra from 3.7 to 3.9. Start time has decreased to 10-20 minutes.